# How can I combine two displacement without the face normal changes of one screwing up the other?

Tags: animation, normals, displacement

I'm looking to apply an animated displacement to a surface which has already been displaced with a cloud texture (creating an organic lumpy base surface).

It should look like this...

[image: Temporary objects / creatures pressing against membrane]

...applied to this...

[image]

...but instead it looks like this:

[image: Disaster!]

Source files [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52011) and [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52012).

The problem is that the normals changed by the first displacement completely screw up the second displacement (I think).

Does anybody know how I can achieve the double displacement of my dreams? I think I need to find a way to redirect the surface normals after the first displacement, but I'm open to any suggestions from you wonderful people.

Comment: because you are using *normal* as direction, when you apply noise first, you change the normals - you noise them - so you also apply noise to the second displacement. You need to switch their order and distort with noise in world space.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my tests this resulted in a lot of the same issues - distortions in the deformation, triangle mash all over the place. However, I think I have a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the effect I desired by using the [Warp modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/warp.html) after a displace modifier to provide initial organic displacement. Performance in Blender was much slower, but as I'm baking the results this was a non-issue.

[image]